# Combination of arrowed list and boxes in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to make a figure showing some info using tikz. At first it looked OK, but after a while everything had moved so nothing was aligned. I figured that there probably is a much better way to do this, so that things cannot move around, but I have not been able to find a way to make such a list connected to boxes. Suggestions on how to make this in a better way is appreciated!

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,arrows}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node[draw, fit={(0,0)(7,1.2)}] (Meta)          at (3,0)    {Metaheuristic layer};

    \node[draw,align=left]          (Destruction)   at (0,-2)   {Destruction\\heuristics};
    \node[draw,align=left]          (Construction)  at (3,-2)   {Construction\\heuristics};
    \node[draw,align=left]          (Local)         at (6,-2)   {Local search\\heurstics};

    \node (toDestruction)   at (0,-.6){};
    \node (toLocal)         at (6,-.6){};

    \node (topDestruction)      at (-.5,-2.315){};
    \node (bottomDestruction)   at (-.5,-4.68){};
    \node (topConstruction)     at (2.5,-2.315){};
    \node (bottomConstruction)  at (2.5,-5.22){};
    \node (topLocal)            at (5.5,-2.315){};
    \node (bottomLocal)         at (5.5,-4.32){};

    \path[->, >=triangle 45, auto, semithick]
        (toDestruction) edge (Destruction)
        (Meta)          edge (Construction)
        (toLocal)       edge (Local);

    \path
        (topDestruction)    edge (bottomDestruction)
        (topConstruction)   edge (bottomConstruction)
        (topLocal)          edge (bottomLocal);

    \node[label=right:Remove K] (RemoveK)   at (-.3,-3){};
    \node[align=left] (RemoveKSR)   at (1.0,-3.8){Remove K\\same route};
    \node[align=left] (MakeK)       at (1.15,-4.78){Make K\\feasible gaps};

    \node[label=right:Fill the gap] (FTG)   at (2.7,-3){};
    \node[label=right:K-regret]     (Kreg)  at (2.7,-3.6){};
    \node[align=left] (Solomon) at (3.6,-4.3){Solomon\\insertion};
    \node[align=left] (GNN)     at (3.83,-5.5){Generalized\\nearest\\neighbour};

    \node[label=right:2-exchange] (2ex)     at (5.7,-3){};
    \node[label=right:2-interchange] (2in)  at (5.7,-3.6){};
    \node[label=right:Resequence]   (res)   at (5.7,-4.2){};

    \path[->]
        (-.5,-3)    edge (-.1,-3)
        (-.5,-3.6)  edge (-.1,-3.6)
        (-.5,-4.55) edge (-.1,-4.55)
        (2.5,-3)    edge (2.9,-3)
        (2.5,-3.6)  edge (2.9,-3.6)
        (2.5,-4.1)  edge (2.9,-4.1)
        (2.5,-5.1)  edge (2.9,-5.1)
        (5.5,-3)    edge (5.9,-3)
        (5.5,-3.6)  edge (5.9,-3.6)
        (5.5,-4.2)  edge (5.9,-4.2);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

When I change the font size to 12pt, this is what happens:

[image: example2]

Comment: @olagjo It's there.

Comment: The only thing that got moved were the location of the arrows relative to the first line of a multiline node.  You could use [base right=(arrow location)] and \parbox[t] inside the node.  Or you could just change the scale factor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a way that uses `tikz trees`. Many style definitions were used.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[edge from parent fork down,
edge from parent/.style={draw,-latex},
every node/.style={thin, minimum height=2.5em},
supervisor/.style={level distance=1cm,text centered, text width=8cm},
teammate/.style={align=left, text width=2cm,level distance=1cm},
subordinate/.style={grow=down, xshift=1cm, align=left, text width=3cm, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.205) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}},
    level1/.style ={level distance=1cm},
    level2/.style ={level distance=2cm},
    level3/.style ={level distance=3cm},
    level4/.style ={level distance=4.5cm},
]

    \node[draw,supervisor]{Metaheuristic layer}

    child[sibling distance=3cm,draw]{node [draw,teammate] {Destruction\\heuristics}
        child[subordinate,level1] {node {Remove K}}
        child[subordinate,level2] {node {Remove K\\same route}}
        child[subordinate,level3] {node {Make K\\feasible gaps}}}
    %
    child[sibling distance=3cm]{node [draw,teammate] {Construction\\heuristics}
        child[subordinate,level1] {node {Fill the gap}}
        child[subordinate,level2] {node {K-regret}}
        child[subordinate,level3] {node {Solomon\\insertion}}
        child[subordinate,level4] {node {Generalized\\nearest\\neighbour}}}
    %
    child[sibling distance=3cm]{node [draw,teammate] {Local search\\heurstics}
        child[subordinate,level1] {node {2-exchange}}
        child[subordinate,level2] {node {2-interchange}}
        child[subordinate,level3] {node {Resequence}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could always use `forest`... (especially good if you dislike typing!). I've also updated the arrows syntax to use the `arrows.meta` library which is now recommended.

Almost all of the work is done in the setup of the tree using `where level=n{}{}` where `n` is the relevant level of the tree, starting with the root node at 0. The way the edge is drawn is varied by setting `edge path` and the start and end points are set using the `parent anchor` and `child anchor` keys. `l sep` is the minimum distance between levels and `s sep` the minimum distance between sibling nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5,12pt,mult,varwidth]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}

  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      where level=0{
        align=center,
        s sep+=10pt,
        l sep+=10pt,
      }{
        align=left,
        where level=1{
          edge path={
            \noexpand\path [semithick, -{Triangle[]}, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor -| .child anchor) -- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
          },
          draw,
        }{
          l sep=0pt,
          child anchor=west,
          anchor=west,
          parent anchor=west,
          edge path={
            \noexpand\path [->, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor -| .child anchor) +(-15pt,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
          },
        },
      },
    }
    [Metaheuristic layer, name=ml
      [Destruction\\heuristics, name=dh
        [Remove K
          [Remove K\\same route
            [Make K\\feasible gaps
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [Construction\\heuristics
        [Fill the gap
          [K-regret
            [Solomon\\insertion
              [Generalized\\nearest\\neighbour
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [Local search\\heuristics, name=lsh
        [2-exchange
          [2-interchange
            [Resequence
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    \node [draw, inner ysep=0pt, inner xsep=20pt, fit=(ml) (dh |- ml) (lsh |- ml)] {};
  \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: forest tree]

Or if you would like a fancier version, this tweaks the thickness of the lines and uses a TiKZ style for the boxes. This has some additional overhead in terms of libraries loaded (but you could avoid these additions if you don't want the shadows).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5,12pt,mult,varwidth]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,arrows.meta,shadows,backgrounds}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}

  \tikzset{
    shadowed box/.style={
      drop shadow,
      draw,
      ultra thick,
      fill=white,
    }
  }

  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      where level=0{
        align=center,
        s sep+=10pt,
        l sep+=10pt,
      }{
        align=left,
        where level=1{
          edge path={
            \noexpand\path [thick, -{Triangle[]}, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor -| .child anchor) -- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
          },
          shadowed box,
        }{
          l sep=0pt,
          child anchor=west,
          anchor=west,
          parent anchor=west,
          edge path={
            \noexpand\path [->, thick, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor -| .child anchor) +(-15pt,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
          },
        },
      },
    }
    [Metaheuristic layer, name=ml
      [Destruction\\heuristics, name=dh
        [Remove K
          [Remove K\\same route
            [Make K\\feasible gaps
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [Construction\\heuristics
        [Fill the gap
          [K-regret
            [Solomon\\insertion
              [Generalized\\nearest\\neighbour
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [Local search\\heuristics, name=lsh
        [2-exchange
          [2-interchange
            [Resequence
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \node [shadowed box, inner ysep=0pt, inner xsep=20pt, fit=(ml) (dh |- ml) (lsh |- ml)] {};
    \end{scope}
  \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: fancier forest]